# SharePoint 2013 dropdown menu for language

Tags: dropdown

How can I make dropdown menu for site language selection in SharePoint 2013 so that users can choose what language they prefer?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to have the language pack installed for all the language options which you want to show in your dropdown menu.
2. Now you can create a html dropdown list and place it anywhere , like inside masterpage or in a CEWP etc etc.
3. Now SharePoint 2013 UI language is the default browser language and to override that you can set a cookie '**lcid**' to the dropdown selected value.

Below is the JavaScript code for that:

```
<script type ="text/javascript"> 

function ChangeUILanguage(value)
{
    var today = new Date();
    var oneYear = new Date(today.getTime() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    var url = window.location.href;
    document.cookie = "lcid=" + value + ";path=/;expires=" + oneYear.toGMTString();
    window.location.href = url;
}

</script>
```

Call this JavaScript method onchange  event of the drop down list.

Comment: will this code get users to choose what language they want to use in online SharePoint 2013? what i want to know is the steps on how external users can choose the language on the site based on drop down list menu. please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

or if you want to keep it clean and not code stuff you simply change the browser language.

Example:

settings --> internet settings --> languages and change the language to the one you need.

This requires that you have downloaded language packs for your browser ofc.